# Передача замыкания используя enum

Tags: rust

**Задача:** Передать замыкание используя enum в другой поток.

**Пример:**

```
pub enum Test<'b> {
    string(&'b str),
    function(Fn() -> View + Send + Sync + 'static)
}
pub fn test_fn<'b>(&mut self, build:Test<'b>) -> View {
   match build {
        Test::string(s) => ...,
        Test::function(fn) => fn()
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В определении типа как минимум две проблемы:

1. Туда зашита временно одолженная ссылка на строку, что делает передачу между потоками проблематичной: `std::thread::spawn()` и похожие функции требуют `'static`, и правильно делают.
2. Такой enum невозможен: вариант `function` не имеет фиксированного размера, т.к. содержит любое соответствующее замыкание в прямом виде.

Попробуйте такое:

```
enum Test {
    String(String),
    Closure(Box<Fn() -> View + Send + 'static>)
}
```